# Rails association, I want something but the other model shouldn't care

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model-associations

So I think I need help with what I am doing with my asscoiations.  I have two models (well many but for the purposes here).  One is a Provider.  Each provider can have a designation.  Though the Designations is just a list it can appear in many different providers so it is not one to one.  My models are as follows:

Provider.rb

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
 has_one :designation
 has_one :specialty
end
```

Designation.rb

```
class Designation < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

The error I get is this:
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: designations.provider_id: SELECT "designations".* FROM "designations" WHERE "designations"."provider_id" = ? LIMIT 1

Which tells me my associations are off cause the designations should not have the provider_id, if anything the provider should have the designation_id.

Do I ditch the has_one and just put has_many in the Designation?

If I do that, I am new to rails, do I have to create a migration so the database is correctly updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
models/provider.rb

belongs_to :designation
```

Then in

```
models/designation.rb

has_many :providers
```

It may feel a little strange but the belongs_to just lets you know which model the id column needs to go in. In this case the provider model, so you'll need:

```
rails g migration add_designation_id_to_provider designation_id:integer
```

Comment: that totally did it.  It does feel very strange to have the belongs_to but it does end up making sense.  Thanks!